# BeautifulSoup doesn't find a specific tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape the stocks markets' names from euronext. The problem is that BeautifulSoup doesn't find the `<td>...</td>` tag, where the name of the stock is stored:

The page has:

```
<td class="stocks-name sorting_1" data-order="1000MERCIS"><a href="/en/product/equities/FR0010285965-ALXP/1000mercis/almil/quotes" data-order="1000MERCIS" data-title-hover="1000MERCIS">1000MERCIS</a></td>
```

And I wrote:

```
url = "https://live.euronext.com/en/products/equities/list"

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS).content
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
names = soup_data.find_all("td", attrs={"id":"stocks-name sorting_1"})
print(names)
```

I only get:

```
[]
```

Thanks

Comment: The URL you provided does not include a single `<td>` element in the page it returns.  If you see one in your browser, it's either a different iframe, or some dynamic element created by javascript in response to other data.

Comment: It might be dynamic, any advise on what to use for scrape those name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    params = {
        "mics": "ALXB,ALXL,ALXP,XPAR,XAMS,XBRU,XLIS,XMLI,MLXB,ENXB,ENXL,TNLA,TNLB,XLDN,XESM,XMSM,XATL,VPXB,XOSL,XOAS,MERK",
        "display_datapoints": "dp_stocks",
        "display_filters": "df_stocks"
    }
    data = {
        "draw": "1",
        "columns[0][data]": "0",
        "columns[0][name]": "",
        "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
        "columns[0][orderable]": "true",
        "columns[0][search][value]": "",
        "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
        "columns[1][data]": "1",
        "columns[1][name]": "",
        "columns[1][searchable]": "true",
        "columns[1][orderable]": "false",
        "columns[1][search][value]": "",
        "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
        "columns[2][data]": "2",
        "columns[2][name]": "",
        "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
        "columns[2][orderable]": "false",
        "columns[2][search][value]": "",
        "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
        "columns[3][data]": "3",
        "columns[3][name]": "",
        "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
        "columns[3][orderable]": "false",
        "columns[3][search][value]": "",
        "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
        "columns[4][data]": "4",
        "columns[4][name]": "",
        "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
        "columns[4][orderable]": "false",
        "columns[4][search][value]": "",
        "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
        "columns[5][data]": "5",
        "columns[5][name]": "",
        "columns[5][searchable]": "true",
        "columns[5][orderable]": "false",
        "columns[5][search][value]": "",
        "columns[5][search][regex]": "false",
        "columns[6][data]": "6",
        "columns[6][name]": "",
        "columns[6][searchable]": "true",
        "columns[6][orderable]": "false",
        "columns[6][search][value]": "",
        "columns[6][search][regex]": "false",
        "order[0][column]": "0",
        "order[0][dir]": "asc",
        "start": "0",
        "length": "100",
        "search[value]": "",
        "search[regex]": "false",
        "iDisplayLength": "2000",
        "iDisplayStart": "0",
        "sSortDir_0": "asc"
    }
    r = requests.post(url, params=params, data=data).json()
    allin = {'Names': []}
    for x in r['aaData']:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(x[0], 'lxml')
        allin['Names'].append(soup.a.text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
    print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://live.euronext.com/en/pd/data/stocks')
```

Output:

```
                   Names
0             1000MERCIS
1           2020 BULKERS
2                  2CRSI
3            2MX ORGANIC
4         2MX ORGANIC BS
...                  ...
1740         ZCI LIMITED
1741       ZENITH ENERGY
1742  ZENOBE GRAMME CERT
1743               ZWIPE
1744   ØRN SOFTWARE HLD.

[1745 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anyway, the problem was that the page updates the tab dynamicaly?